# DB2 transaction isolation per schema

Tags: java, sql, transactions, db2-400

I am using DB2 6.1 AS/400 and System i Navigator. 
Is it possible, that two different schemas have two dfferent isolation levels?
Currently I am working on two schemas, one dedicated for development, the second one for testing. The first one was set about 4 month ago, the second one few days ago.

I am running a Java based web application that runs some SQL statements from java code, and finally calls stored procedure. Generally thare is a select for update statement as well as some insert select statements. All operations are done with one connection with disabled auto commit. What is interesting, when I run application on development schema everything works fine. When I switch to test schema (the only change is in a config of the application) I get timeouts in procedure because of locks on some tables. I have no idea why. Exactly the same code passes fine on production schema.

Is it possible? Can I check it somehow in the System i Navigator?

Answer (score 1):

No, Isolation level is a statement level property.

There's no way to specify a per schema isolation level.

Even the connection isolation level is simply a default to use if the statement doesn't explicitly set it.

Show exactly what you're changing to change schemas.

Answer (score 0):

I change only config file: db.schema=test or db.schema=dev. Thats all. I concatenate each statement in code with the value of property db.schema from config.